# How to include non PyPi packages for virtualenv requirements file?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pypy

Is there a way to include packages/modules not available through pip in the requirements file so that the project is portable?

The default version of lxml seems to have issues with pypy so I need to use a [custom fork](https://github.com/aglyzov/lxml).

The problem is I need Heroku (where I deploy this application) to use a custom version of lxml and not the one that's available via pip. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What issues with lxml do you have?  Please report them as pypy bugs.  (lxml-cffi is no longer recommended since a while.)

Comment: @ArminRigo Keep seeing an error while building "conflicting types for 'Py_hash_t' and the install fails with the error message "'cc' failed with exit status 1."  Can't really find anything online and I'm not too familiar with build processes.. Is there a reason lxml-cffi is not recommended anymore?

Comment: lxml-cffi is old at this point, and was never 100% complete.  If it's enough for your use case, then fine I suppose.  About the error, I think it was fixed some time ago; are you using pypy 5.3 or some older version?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Looking more, the fix is more recent than the latest release.  The problem should show up on some 32-bit environments, but not 64-bit; but the details are probably not too important as it is fixed for the upcoming pypy 5.4 release.  It can also be fixed manually by removing the ``typedef Py_ssize_t Py_hash_t;`` line in pypy's include/pyport.h .

Comment: @ArminRigo  I'll try a 64bit distro and see if the issue disappears

Comment: @ArminRigo switched to a 64bit version of Ubuntu and the default branch seems to work fine now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by using [the listed git packages syntax](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#id9), you would need to add the following line to your requirements.txt

```
-e git://github.com/aglyzov/lxml.git#egg=lxml
```